# Which particle(s) can be used to list nominalised verbs?

Tags: particles, sentence-final-particles, english-to-japanese, nominalization

Here's the sentence I'm trying to express in Japanese.
"I have changed my life, I've become a cheerful person, all because of him!"

And this is how I would translate it.
僕の人生が変わったのや、明るい人になったのは、全部彼のおかげなんだ！

Am I using the right particles? My intuition says that the sentence is wrong.

Comment: @Blavius "Connect verbs"?  The の nominalizes the verb already.

Comment: Make that an answer if you are confident of what you are saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「[僕]{ぼく}の[人生]{じんせい}が[変]{か}わったのや、[明]{あか}るい[人]{ひと}になったのは、[全部彼]{ぜんぶかれ}のおかげなんだ！」

is grammatical and even sounds fairly natural.

The only part that does not quite sound natural is 「明るい**人**」.  We would rarely use 「人」 that way to refer to oneself, but again, it is still all grammatical.  You could say 「明るくなった」.

> Am I using the right particles?

Yes, you are.  I would never call anything natural here when there is a particle mistake.

The third-person pronoun 「彼」 is not something we native speakers use often, but I certainly could not say it is wrong to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I always get unsure which particle is right since I've only bothered to learn the very basic grammar.